# Define constraints of variables

Tags: python, dictionary, expression

Is there any canonical way to define constraints for variables? Specifically, is there good way to implement the method `isgood`:

```
>>> isgood({'a': 1, 'b': 3}, '2*a != b')
True
>>> isgood({'a': 1, 'b': 2}, '2*a != b')
False
>>> isgood({'a': 1, 'b': 3}, '2*a != b and a + 1 == 3')
False
```

My main problem is how to define constraints? What's the type of the constraints? In the example, I define it as list of strings, but is there any way to specify the requeriments of values?

Comment: The type of the constraints seems to be `str`. Was this your question?

Comment: This looks like a school or an interview assignment. While it is not prohibited in SO to ask such questions you need to ask specifically where you need help, what you don't understand and what you have tried so far (or even thinking of trying). Right now you are asking us: "What is this and can you do it for me?"

Comment: That being said, it looks like [`eval()`](https://realpython.com/python-eval-function/) is what you need.

Comment: `eval` won't help here, `2a` isn't valid Python syntax.

Comment: That's true. My bad. I would assume it would require some sort of expression parsing module. Maybe one for which you can define your own grammar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the builtin Python function `eval()` to do this. For example,

```py
def isgood(mydict: dict, constraints) -> bool:
    """It checks if the dict fits the constraints"""
    
    for k, v in mydict.items():
        constraints = constraints.replace(k, "({})".format(v))
    
    return eval(constraints)
```

Note that `constraints` must be a Python expression. Namely, as pointed out by  mkrieger1 in a comment, the above code only works if you used `2*a` instead of `2a`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but with `isgood({'a': 1, 'b': 3, 'c': -2}, "2*a == b")` I get this error: `2*mydimydict['c']t['a'] == mydimydict['c']t['b'] SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: If you put `for k in mydict.keys(): value = mydict[k]; constraints = constraints.replace(k, "({})".format(value))` it works

Comment: Edited to fix the error